# JavaFx ProgressIndicator while Loading Pane (GUI)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, loading

In my application, I have to build big panes with a lot of content. I will show a ProgressIndicator while the GUI is loading.

My first test, I will show a ProgressIndicator while I adding a lot of tabs into a TabPane.

That's my test Code:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    ProgressIndicator myProgressIndicator;
    Task<Void> myLongTask;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        myProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        Pane p1 = new Pane(myProgressIndicator);
        tabPane = new TabPane();
        Pane p2 = new Pane(tabPane);


        myLongTask = new Task<Void>()
        {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception
        {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
//          Thread.sleep(10);
            Tab newTab = new Tab("Number:" + i);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
        }
        return null;
        }
        };
        borderPane.centerProperty().bind(Bindings.when(myLongTask.runningProperty()).then(p1).otherwise(p2));

        new Thread(myLongTask).start();
    }
}
```

But the application will show the window if the Task has finished. If I replace the lines inside the for-loop with `Thread.sleep(10)` the application show the Indicator and, after all, sleep, it shows the GUI.

How can I show an Indicator while the GUI is not loaded already?

Comment: `tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);` is modifying the UI on a background thread, which you are not allowed to do (see, e.g. the "Threading" section of the [`Application` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Task` that creates a result (i.e. a `TabPane`). Therefore it's more convenient to use `TabPane` as type parameter instead of `Void` also you should call [`updateProgress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-long-long-) to update the [`progress` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#progressProperty) and bind that property to [the `progress` property of the `ProgressIndicator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty).

The result can be added to the `BorderPane` in the [`onSucceded` handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty) instead of creating a (more or less) complicated binding:

```
Task<TabPane> myLongTask;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    myLongTask = new Task<TabPane>() {

        @Override
        protected TabPane call() throws Exception {
            TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
            List<Tab> tabs = tabPane.getTabs();
            final int count = 1000 - 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                Tab newTab = new Tab("Number:" + i);
                tabs.add(newTab);
                updateProgress(i, count);
            }
            return tabPane;
        }
    };
    myLongTask.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
        // update ui with results
        tabPane = myLongTask.getValue();
        borderPane.setCenter(new Pane(tabPane));
    });
    
    // add progress indicator to show progress of myLongTask
    myProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    myProgressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(myLongTask.progressProperty());
    borderPane.setCenter(new Pane(myProgressIndicator));

    new Thread(myLongTask).start();
}
```

Simply creating the tabs is fast however, and you won't see any progress indicator in the UI. Layouting a `TabPane` with 999 `Tabs` however is rather slow. The UI will most likely freeze for a short time. You can work around this by adding only a limited number of `Tab`s in each frame:

Return a `List<Tab>` from the task instead of a `TabPane`; these `Tab`s should not be added to the `TabPane` (yet). You can use a `AnimationTimer` to add a fixed number of tabs each frame:

```
final List<Tab> result = ...; // your tab list

// number of elements added each frame
final int step = 5;

final int size = result.size();
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

    int index = 0;
            
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(result.subList(index, Math.min(size, index+step)));
        index += step;
        if (index >= size) {
            this.stop();
        }
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Comment: @kayf: Creating the 999 `Tab`s is fast; Layouting a `TabPane` with 999 `Tab`s is not. Your UI will freeze during the layouting. (see answer update)

Answer (score 0):

I have change the class like this:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;
ProgressIndicator myProgressIndicator;
Task<List<Tab>> myLongTask;
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
        myLongTask = new Task<List<Tab>>()
        {
            @Override
            protected List<Tab> call() throws Exception
            {
            List<Tab> newTabs = new ArrayList<Tab>();
            final int count = 1000 - 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                Tab newTab = new Tab("Number:" + i);
                newTabs.add(newTab);
            }
            return newTabs;
            }
        };

    myProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    myProgressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(myLongTask.progressProperty());
    borderPane.setCenter(new Pane(myProgressIndicator));

    new Thread(myLongTask).start();

    myLongTask.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
    final List<Tab> result = myLongTask.getValue();
    final int step = 5;
    final int size = result.size();

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        int index = 0;
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(result.subList(index, Math.min(size, index+step)));
        index += step;
        if (index >= size) {
            this.stop();
        }
        }
    };
        timer.start();
        borderPane.setCenter(new Pane(tabPane));
    });
}
```

}

Is it this what you mean?