# Why is `Stage#show` so slow, and what can be done to accelerate it

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, the first time a stage is shown with `Stage#show` takes a long time. I'm not talking about the time it takes to load FXML (which is a different issue altogether), but simply the time it takes between calling `Stage#show` and the call returning (and the window shown to the user).

I have created this sample application, which creates a random scene with a few tabs, grid panes and table views, then times how long it takes to call `Stage#show`:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Speed test");
        primaryStage.setScene(createScene(3, 3, 6, 8));
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        primaryStage.show();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Total seconds: " + ((double) (end - start)) / 1000000000);
    }

    private Scene createScene(int tabs, int rows, int columns, int tableColumns) {
        TabPane tp = new TabPane();
        for (int t = 0; t < tabs; t++) {
            GridPane gp = new GridPane();
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                    gp.add(getRandomControl(), c, r);
                }
            }
            TableView<Object> tv = new TableView<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableColumns; i++)
                tv.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>(getRandomString()));

            VBox vb = new VBox(gp, tv);
            tp.getTabs().add(new Tab(getRandomString(), vb));
        }
        return new Scene(tp);
    }

    private final String[] randomStrings = new String[]{
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "baz",
            "lorem",
            "ipsum",
            "dolor",
            "sit",
            "amet",
            "adipiscing",
            "elit",
            "morbi",
            "quis",
            "tempus",
            "justo",
            "faucibus",
            "justo",
            "risus",
            "nec",
            "commodo",
            "sem",
            "congue"
    };

    private final Random random = new Random();

    private String getRandomString() {
        return randomStrings[random.nextInt(randomStrings.length)];
    }

    private Control getRandomControl() {
        switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
            case 0:
                return new Label(getRandomString());
            case 1:
                return new TextField();
            case 2:
                return new PasswordField();
            case 3:
                ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
                cb.getItems().addAll(randomStrings);
                return cb;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My results vary, of course, but they are always around 1.2 seconds, which doesn't sound like a lot, but is certainly noticeable, and not too much expected, considering my machine loads comparably complex UIs in a fraction of this time (as long as they're not written in JavaFX, that is).

So my question is - what causes this poor performance? Are there some tricks or hacks to minimize this time, similar to what is done to accelerate FXML loading?

Comment: I get between about 0.6s and 0.9s on my system. Note that if you repeat the same test with a new stage once the first one is displayed (just add an event handler to the scene that invoked the same code), subsequent showing of the stages are much faster (I get about a 6-fold improvement). So I suspect some of the startup of the FX toolkit is deferred until the first time a stage is shown. There probably isn't a whole lot you can do if the delay is starting up the toolkit.

Comment: As a runnable jar this starts up between 0.44 and 0.59 seconds on my system. I wouldn't call that an issue for a multiplatform application that runs in a virtual machine. If necessary, the trick is to do what other applications do if loading takes longer: show a splash screen. But then again, how often do you start an app? Also, if you want more "stress-test", just launch the [JavaFX ensemble](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html). That's heavy and starts up within a second on my system.

Comment: It's not the scene construction that's taking that long, it's the layouting. If I initially add no content to the `TabPane` and add the tabs later (Setting the `Scene` size manually) it's taking `0.1< t < 0.2 s` compared to `0.75 < t < 0.85s`. The OP encountered a similar issue when trying out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35082959/2991525 , so I posted a workaround at the end of the question. I didn't have the time to test it thoroughly though, but maybe it helps nonetheless...

Comment: Thank you, this is all interesting feedback. Is there any way to have the layout be done on a different thread, thus freeing the UI thread until the content is ready to be displayed? This way I can show a minimal UI which still feels responsive. But I suspect it can't be done, as the layout mechanism is too tightly bound to the UI/Toolkit?