# Prerendering complex Forms in JavaFX?

Tags: forms, performance, javafx, render, prerender

I've got a fairly complex Form (around 500 nested nodes) which takes 2-3 seconds to render on my system. As soon as i place the Form inside a Scene, all other animated controls like ProgressIndicators freeze their animation loop until the Form was displayed.

From a users perspective this feels laggy and unresponsive.

The Form has no bindings or heavy lifting, which could be moved to another Thread, nor is it a FXML.

Is there a way or common workaround to pre-render a Form in a parallel FX-Thread?

Comment: I suspect, though not sure, this can't be done. There is some relevant discussion in the comments to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214022/why-is-stageshow-so-slow-and-what-can-be-done-to-accelerate-it).

Comment: Any chance you could provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody could try this out.  Otherwise it is pretty hard to advise.