# Show progress while loading FXML file

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

JavaFX application has a tree menu and clicking on a menu item loads an fxml file  [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5srQ.png)

Some of the FXMLs are nested and are taking up to 2-3 seconds to load. I would like to show a progress indicator while FXMLs are getting loaded and initialized. Controller's initialization code can be executed as a Task and bind it's progress to a progress bar control, but the problem is that some of code needs to be executed in FX Application thread using Platform.runLater(). If I do that, there is no way to know when the initialization is completed.

Is there a way to handle this seemingly simple task ?

I cannot share the controller code which is taking long time to load, but for the purpose of this question, please **assume** the following initialization code is the culprit. I cannot execute this block of code in a Task thread as UI changes cannot be made from threads other than JavaFX Application thread. If I wrap the part of code that changes UI inside Platform.runLater(), task **may** finish it's execution even before the UI changes are completed.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    if (webEngine == null) {
        webEngine = helpView.getEngine();
    }
    try {
        Path filepath = Paths.get("docs/index.html");
        webEngine.load(filepath.toUri().toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Failed to read doc files", ButtonType.OK);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Raj

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214022/why-is-stageshow-so-slow-and-what-can-be-done-to-accelerate-it), which also links to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081031/javafx-progressindicator-while-loading-pane-gui/35082959#35082959).

Comment: It should not take 2-3 seconds to load an FXML file and display it. If the data loading (which should be in the model, not in the controller) is taking time, you can, as you suggest, perform that in a task. I don't understand "there is no way to know when the initialization is completed": surely it is completed when the task finishes. Create a [MCVE] showing an example that demonstrates the problem and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Have edited my question with relevant code snippet